# condition from UDP data doens't work in PYTHON

Tags: python, udp

I would like to make condition from datas from UDP with Python.
here's my code:

```
import socket
import atexit
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 8002

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print("listen to port: " + str(UDP_PORT))
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    data = data.rsplit(",")
    data = data.pop(0)
    print(data)
    if data=='1':
        print("BOOL is TRUE")
```

"BOOL is true should be printed when data==1, but nothing occurs... 
Any clue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: right now you are checking if `data` equals `"1"` which is different from `1`.  One is a string, one is a number.  Are you intending to check if it is equal to the string?

Comment: Does it ever do the `print(data)`? If so, could you try something like `print('[', data, ']')` to ensure there are no spaces or anything?

Comment: @ryan: when I print('[...] as you say, it gives me:
('[', '1\x00\x00\x00', ']')
or when the result is 0: ('[', '0\x00\x00\x00', ']')
ouch ! little bit lost here...

Comment: BTW - If you're not using Python 3, you should use the `print` statement (i.e. `print data`, not `print(data)`) unless you import `print_function` from future.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
data = data.pop(0)
```

with this:

```
data = data.pop(0).strip('\x00')
```

This will remove the `NULL`s that are padding the string.

Alternatively, you could look into why the values are being `NULL` padded and fix it on the server side.